# How to set different Time zones in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Hi I Have a Hotel Management system, in this for different hotels(Subdomains) different Time zones are required. how can i do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's very nice [Django documentation regarding timezones](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/).  You'll need to determine exactly what you mean when you say you'd like a different time zone per subdomain.  Normally, the Django `TIME_ZONE` setting is used to specify a default time zone.  In your case however, you effectively want a different default `TIME_ZONE` setting depending on which subdomain is being accessed.

Probably the most robust way to achieve this goal is:

- Always store dates in your UTC, independent of the time zone allocated to a sub domain.
- Write some custom Django Middleware which will set the default time zone to use when each request arrives.  The Django documentation linked above gives an example.  Here's an example:

```js
import django.utils.timezone
from pytz import timezone

class TimezoneMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        # Put logic here to choose timezone based on domain.
        if request.META['HTTP_HOST'] == 'hotel1.subdomain.com':
            tz = timezone('US/Eastern')
        else:
            tz = timezone('UTC')

        if tz:
            django.utils.timezone.activate(tz)
        else:
            django.utils.timezone.deactivate()
```

Now, when Django handles date entered or displayed, it will use the timezone selected by middleware.   This doesn't solve the problem of having users in a different time zone to the subdomain for which the time zone is set.  Normally, this problem would be solved by having each Django user store their preferred time zone, and the middleware would choose the time zone based on their session data as described in the documentation.

Comment: @Austin will this tz will be activated for this session only? What if there are multiple concurrent requests?

Comment: @AnuragRana The tz will be activated for this *request* only (not session).  The django timezone activate/deactivate functions use thread-local storage to store the currently activated timezone in order to support concurrent requests, each which may have their own timezone.  The current Django docs contain a more up-to-date middleware example than given in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Below code can be used to change timezone.

```
import os,time

os.environ['TZ'] = 'Asia/Shanghai'
```

There is a list of timezone in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones.

[Pytz](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz/) is another good choice to manage timezone in python.

Comment: If using this method, be aware that you may need to call `time.tzset()` after setting `TZ`.  Also, using a global variable like this has the potential for environment conflicts when deployed in webserver environments that use different threads in the same process to handle different requests.  Because `TZ` is effectively a global variable in this case, you may find that a request being handled in another thread overwrites your own thread's `TZ` environment variable.