# Django Timezone Awareness - Data to be stored in UTC

Tags: python, django, postgresql, datetime, timezone

This is my first time developing a timezone aware web app.  I'm using Django 1.11.7.  I have looked through many posts regarding timezones and honestly, I'm starting to feel like I just don't understand the concept of timezones... 0_o

I'm making a booking app with `start_time` and `end_time` for each reservation.

I expect the user to be able to enter dates and times as he experiences them in his timezone.  On the other hand, I want these dates and times stored in a postgresql database in UTC format.

[image: Five hour timezone difference between UTC and Ottawa]

If I was choosing to reserve, for example, between 12am and 2am (today), the result in the database should show between 5pm and 7pm (today).
Right?

Django Internationalization settings:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_TZ = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_I18N = True
```

During database creation:

```
start_time      TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
end_time        TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL
```

Using Django's built in admin page feature, I enter the following information:

[image: Admin form showing note about the time difference]

But when I look up the results in the database, here's what I get:

```
2017-12-05 19:00:00-05 | 2017-12-05 20:59:59-05
```

The stored result changed in the opposite direction of what I was expecting.  I was expecting:

```
2017-12-06 05:00:00+05 | 2017-12-06 07:00:00+05
```

If my expectations are wrong and everything is working fine, I would be grateful if you could explain to me how I should interpret the timezone when I read it.

Otherwise, if my expectations where right, I would appreciate any advice.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Next time, please [insert images inline](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images) using the editor button rather than just linking to external sites. I've done it for you on this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic issue here is that you've misunderstood what the admin is doing for you ("I expect the user to be able to enter dates and times as he experiences them in his timezone"). In fact, the admin interprets all datetimes in the server time zone (`UTC` in your case).

> Note: You are 5 hours behind server time

actually means:

> Warning: The values you enter here will be interpreted in the server timezone, which is 5 hours ahead of you.

(I agree with you that this wording is ambiguous. You might want to [file a ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/newticket) about improving it.)

For background on this issue, see [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20663#comment:12). The root of the problem is that there's no way to get the user's timezone in the browser. What you can do is compare the current time in the browser to the current time on the server and post the warning above if they are different.

If you want to interpret datetimes in the user's timezone, there's no alternative but to ask the user to indicate their timezone explicitly, record it somewhere, and then `activate()` it to make it the current timezone. This is the technique [described in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone). I believe that there are third-party packages that provide timezone selection widgets based on the list of timezones in pytz.

You're also misreading the time display. I think what you were expecting is `2017-12-06 05:00:00+00`. Instead the result is `2017-12-06 00:00:00+00` in `UTC` or, equivalently, `2017-12-05 19:00:00-05` in Ottawa time, which is what you reported.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.google.co.jp/search?dcr=0&q=ottawa+timezone&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjX0LnA5_bXAhVFjJQKHXCdBDYQvwUIJigA&biw=1394&bih=803

Ottawa timezone is -5.

You can manually test in a template that's the timezones are properly registered by showing the time you've registered in different timezones with this filter:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/timezones/#std:templatefilter-timezone

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue with Hotel bookings. This answer put me on the right track.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18307581/4660189

The key here is in what you said:

> I expect the user to be able to enter dates and times as he experiences them in his timezone.

"his timezone" would need to be handled via a middleware. So that each user can be assigned a timezone, and thus the system would handle all times/dates for this user accordingly.

This should get you going. Happy coding and welcome to the mind bending reality of timezones.